# \fbox does not work with images

Tags: fonts, graphics

I tray to add a border on a list of images using `\fbox` but it did not work.

my code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \fbox{
      \mbox{\subfigure[Frame 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}
             \subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}}\\
            \mbox{ \subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im3.png}}
             \subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im4.png}}}\\
              \mbox{\subfigure[Frame 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im5.png}}
                     \subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm{im6.png}}}\\                    
                      \mbox{\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm{im7.png}}
                     \subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im8.png}}
                     } 
                    }

     \caption{cc.} 
     \label{fbox}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get this error `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. }`. When i remove the \fbox all things are going. thanks to help me.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Adam, sorry, I edited my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have each subfigure surrounded with a frame, place the `\fbox` inside the `\subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[Frame 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}}\\
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im3.png}}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im4.png}}}\\
\subfigure[Frame 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im5.png}}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im6.png}}}\\                    
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im7.png}}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im8.png}}}
\caption{cc.} 
\label{fbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have only one frame, you can do:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\subfigure[Frame 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im1.png}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im2.png}}\\
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im3.png}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im4.png}}\\
\subfigure[Frame 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im5.png}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im6.png}}\\                    
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im7.png}}
\subfigure[Foreground silhouette 1]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{im8.png}}
\end{varwidth}}
\caption{cc.} 
\label{fbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

If images on the same row are too close, you could use `\quad`, for example, to add some spacing between them.

By the way, `subfigure` is obsolete; perhaps you should consider using [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). Also, `[!h]` might be too restrictive; try using a more convenient option `[!ht]` or not using none.

Comment: Thanks for your response, How can I put just one border for all the images ? please

Comment: @phdstudent please see my updated answer.